# How to pick which coefficients get printed in statsmodels regression summary

Tags: statsmodels

Is there a way to pick which coefficients get printed from statsmodel's RegressionResults.summary function? For example, it would be great to suppress output for all the incidental parameters in a model with lots of fixed effects.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is what you want to do, as the additional details on the goodness-of-fit and error distributions only make sense in the context of _all_ the parameters. If you leave any out, you can no longer interpret the other results. sukhbinder's answer below shows you how to access the coefficients, but I'd not tamper with `summary` itself.

Answer (score -1):

@djtm15 A little more context and what you have tried will help refine the question.

You are most probably looking for the `params`

```
model.params
```

a complete simple example

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

xdata = np.array([0.0,   1.0,  3.0, 4.3, 7.0,   8.0,   8.5, 10.0, 12.0])
ydata = np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.11, 0.43,  0.7, 0.89, 0.95, 0.99])

model = sm.OLS(ydata, sm.add_constant(xdata)).fit()

print model.params
```